# How to query SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have read **[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386940(v=vs.110).aspx)** nice tutorial,  but it doesn't work when I try to connect to SQL Server database.

All I need is to do a simple query like `SELECT * FROM Table` and I need to process the resulting value of that query.

Here's my code, but **it does not print out anything** into the console window and I can't figure out why:

```
    namespace LinqConsoleApplication
    {
        [Table(Name = "Central")]
        public class Central
        {
            private string _UserID;
            [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Storage = "_UserID")]
            public string UserID
            {
                get
                {
                    return this._UserID;
                }
                set
                {
                    this._UserID = value;
                }

            }

        private string _Email;
        [Column(Storage = "_Email")]
        public string Email
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Email;
            }
            set
            {
                this._Email = value;
            }
        }

    } // end of class Central

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Use a connection string.
            DataContext db = new DataContext("Server=aaaaaaa; Database=bbbbbbbbb; uid=ccccccccc; pwd=ddddddddd; Trusted_Connection=True;");

            // Get a typed table to run queries.
            Table<Central> Centrals = db.GetTable<Central>();

            IQueryable<Central> custQuery =
                from central in Centrals
                select central;

            foreach (Central rowin custQuery)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Email={0}", row.Email);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }

 } // end of namespace
```

Comment: how many rows do you have in table?

Comment: This one is easier : http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter

Comment: This will be miuch easier to solve by yourself debugging it? Have you stepped though the code?

Comment: Check your connection string. It should be either UN:PWD or trusted connection  but not both.

Comment: Hi,
From your code there seem to be 2 possible scenarios: 
1. Your code runs fine, which means you actually get to the foreach loop, and means your table is empty.
2. Your code crashes at some earlier point and you havent noticed it, which means your configuration (Connection string and so) are off.

You can find out which one is true by either stepping as Liam suggsested, or adding console write after the for loop to see if your code actually gets there.

Comment: Thank you for help guys! Now it works, I needed to have a little break to chill my brain:)

Answer (score -1):

Simple query from Sql Server and fill it in DataTable, then print all the values:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  try
  {
    const string connString =
      "Data Source=127.0.0.1,1433\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=dbfirealarm;Integrated Security=false;Pooling=False;User ID=admin;Password=admin;Connection Timeout=5";
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
      using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TABLE_LOGGING", conn))
      {
        using (var dataTable = new DataTable())
        {
          adapter.Fill(dataTable);
          PrintDataTable(dataTable);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
  }
}

private static void PrintDataTable(DataTable table)
{
  foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
  {
    Console.Write("{0}\t", column.Caption);
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
  foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
  {
    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
    {
      Console.Write("{0}\t", item);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
}
```